# AsyncTask onPostExecute with Interface

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

OK I must be missing something here, and I can't seen to place my finger on it. Here is my situation, I create my AsyncTask Externally (good practice and reusable), I have no problem connecting to the server, getting the response to my interface with the onPostExecute();, but taking the value from the interface to the Calling class and retaining that value is giving me a problem. Here is an example of my code.

The interface

```
interface getData {
    void done (ArrayList<String> returnedData);
}
```

The AsyncTask and calling method using a wrapper class called serverRequests

```
public void getDataInBackground ( String params, getData retData){
    new getDataAsync(params,retData).execute();
}
public class getDataAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList<String>> {
    String params;
    getData retData;
    public getDataAsync( String params, getData retData){
        this.params=params;
        this.retData=retData;
    }
     @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        //Do a bunch of stuff that connects to my server
        return list;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> returnedData) {
        retData.done(returnedData);
        super.onPostExecute(returnedData);
    }
}
```

Then my Activity Class that calls this process would be like so.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ServerRequests serverRequests; // the Wrapper class to call my different AsyncTasks
    ArrayList<String> someList;
    String params="some kind of params";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_activity);

    serverRequests= new serverRequests(this);//this being the context passed
    someList=new ArrayList<>();

     serverRequests.getDataInBackground(params, new getData() {
        @Override
        public void done(ArrayList<String> returnedData) {
            someList.addAll(returnedData);
            //somelist has data here
            //used AlertDialogs to confirm data
        }
    });
    //someList is empty here and data is needed to perform other tasks.
    // again used AlertDialogs to confirm data
```

Now in this activity I perform several other AsyncTasks collecting data for the end user. The other task data depends on this first call. I have thought about storing the data on the phone temporarily, then I thought of my wife whose phone is always limited on memory space, that could generate an unwanted error. I thought about performing the other AsyncTask inside of this one but then I would be opening up multiple threads needlessly and wasting CPU on the phone. I have tried other suggestions I found on this site like making the someList static/final but that isn't working either. I have also tried just a simple assignment someList=returnedData. So any suggestions on how to get this value from AsyncTask and into the calling method?

Answer (score 1):

Interface is working.

```
//access download task data
public interface MyAccessResponse {
    void postResult(String asyncResult);
}

//download class
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    public MyAccessResponse delegate=null;
    public DownloadTask(MyAccessResponse asyncResponse) {
        delegate = asyncResponse;//Assigning call back interfacethrough constructor
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            //read 1st string
            url = new URL( urls[0] );
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream inpt = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inpt));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String aux = "";

            while ((aux = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(aux);
            }
            return builder.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Log.i("tms delegate", "access delegate");

        //super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result!=null && delegate!=null)
        {
            delegate.postResult(result);
        } else {
            Log.i("MyAccess", "You have not assigned IApiAccessResponse delegate");
        }
    }
} //end of Download Task
```

In onCreate:
...

```
    DownloadTask task =  new DownloadTask(new MyAccessResponse() {

        @Override
        public void postResult(String asyncResult) {
            //html = asyncResult ;
            //Log.i("tms postResult", html);
            //process result--split point: "/imgs/hr_shadow.gif"
            String[] splitResult = asyncResult.split("/imgs/hr_shadow.gif");

            //example: <img src="/celebs/rihanna/thumbs/thumb1.jpg" alt="Rihanna" height="95" width="95" border="0" />
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("src=\"(.*?)\"");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(splitResult[1]);
            while(m.find()) {
                celebURLs.add( m.group(1));
                Log.i("tms src:", m.group(1));
            }

            p = Pattern.compile("alt=\"(.*?)\"");
            m = p.matcher(splitResult[1]);
            while(m.find()) {
                celebNames.add( m.group(1));
                Log.i("tms name:", m.group(1));
            }

            createNewQuestion();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Suggestion: Use Volley or OkHttp instead

Answer (score 0):

Its perfectly acceptable to run a second AsyncTask in the onPostExecute of the first, if the second depends on the result of the first.  You really shouldn't worry about the multiple threads-  first off AsyncTasks are all queued on one thread unless you explicitly request otherwise.  Secondly, your tasks are likely IO bound.  Thirdly, CPU usage is a tiny amount of battery consumption compared to things like GPS and display-  you pretty much have to try to make a dent with it.

Comment: well this is the first of 5 task that the results from the first will be used in the next to generate a Custom ArrayAdatper with fragmented ListView layout. So running 5 nested threads is acceptable to android? I mean unless your facebook I didn't think we could get away with burning up someone's pocket by over heating the phone.

Comment: If those are gong out to network requests you won't be burning CPU anyway-  you're going to be blocking on IO.  If I were you I'd be more concerned about it taking so long to generate a result than I would the CPU usage.  Have you considered creating a more powerful API that can do more of the work on the server to reduce it to 1-2 calls?

Comment: I thought about that which is probably the way i need to go if I can't get the value outside of onPostExetute. I dread that because that means a day of work recreating a webInterface then recreating the Custom Adapter.  So there is no way that you know of the get this value to the calling class, without using the UI thread which others have suggested?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. In the activity class I created a void method to set the value compared to the context. Then when I got my value I sent it to that method. Here is the example.

```
protected void setValue(ArrayList<String> list){
     this.someList=list;}
```

then in my original class activity where I had

```
someList.addAll(returnedData);
```

I replaced it with

```
setValue(returnedData);
```

Thus making the value accessible through out the whole class